# How to get the requested uri

Tags: php, ip-address

I'd like on PHP get the requested URI.

I mean to store into `$address` the string `www.mywebsite.com/index.php?param=1` for example.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 4):

The path without domain name is stored in [`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). In your case, it would be `/index.php?param=1`.

Comment: Domain name is in `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`

Comment: @Zirak: I hesitated to include that in my answer since the PHP manual [made me suspicious](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004298/when-could-the-http-host-header-be-undefined).