# What's the difference of $host and $http_host in Nginx

Tags: configuration, nginx, http-headers

In Nginx, what's the difference between variables `$host` and `$http_host`.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

`$host` is a variable of the [Core](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) module.

> $host

> This variable is equal to line Host in the header of request or
> name of the server processing the request if the Host header is not
> available.

> This variable may have a different value from $http_host in such
> cases: 1) when the Host input header is absent or has an empty value,
> $host equals to the value of server_name directive; 2)when the value
> of Host contains port number, $host doesn't include that port number.
> $host's value is always lowercase since 0.8.17.

`$http_host` is also a variable of the same module but you won't find it with that name because it is defined generically as `$http_HEADER` ([ref](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_http_)).

> $http_HEADER

> The value of the HTTP request header HEADER when converted to lowercase and with 'dashes' converted to 'underscores', e.g. $http_user_agent, $http_referer...;

---

Summarizing:

- `$http_host` equals always the `HTTP_HOST` request header.
- `$host` equals `$http_host`, **lowercase and without the port number** (if present), **except when `HTTP_HOST` is absent or is an empty value**. In that case, `$host` equals the value of the `server_name` directive of the server which processed the request.

Comment: $host is specifically **the first `server_name`** that is defined in the current server block.  if you have multiple `server_name`s, only the first one will appear.

Comment: True. In fact, it is quite typical to define: server_name example.com www.example.com;

Comment: you can have multiple `server_name` directives too. if you happen to have a regex in the first one, that becomes the `$host` , and all sorts of ugly stuff can happen during rewrite rules.

Comment: Does the `$server_name` variable equal the `server_name` directive's value or the actual server name that was selected if there were multiple `server_name` directives?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai `$server_name` is always equal to the first value specified with the server_name directive. For example, with `server_name example.com one.example.com two.example.com;`, `$server_name` will always be "example.com", **regardless of which host the user has specified**. In fact, if you don't have a `default_server`, the host might be something completely different (like example.org).

Comment: Links are kinda 404 now.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer and its comments don't seem to be correct (anymore). The docs (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host) say that `$host` is

> in this order of precedence: host name from the request line, or host name from the “Host” request header field, or the server name matching a request

So `$http_host` is always the value of the `Host` header field. They might differ if the host in the request line (if specified) differs from the `Host` header field. Or if the `Host` header is not set.

`server_name` matches only the `Host` header field (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html), so that `$host` may differ from the matched `server_name`.

Comment: yes, though it is important to note that `$http_host` has still the port included, while `$host` doesn't seem so. Some peculiar settings may need the port to behave well, otherwise they fall on standard settings (port 80/443).

Answer (score 16):

## `$http_host`

`$http_host` always equals `Host` request header field

```
Host: example.org
```

## `$host`

`$host` is in this order of precedence (from high to low):

- Host name from the request line

  ```
  GET http://example.org/test/ HTTP/1.1
  ```
- `Host` request header field
- The `server_name` (in Nginx config) matching a request, even if `server_name` is wildcard (Ex: `server_name *.example.org;`)

### Host name from the request line

When open URL `http://example.org/test/` ...

Most browser send the request like this

```
GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
Host: example.org
```

Most browser doesn't send the request like this (but this is valid request)

```
GET http://example.org/test/ HTTP/1.1
```

---

## Validation

#### Nginx testing config

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  *.example.org;

    location / {
        default_type "text/plain";
        return 200 "[host] = $host";
    }
}
```

#### When all exist ...

`$host` = host name from the request line

```bash
curl http://127.0.0.1 -v \
  --request-target http://request.example.org/test/ \
  --path-as-is \
  -H "Host: host.example.org"
```

This command will

- Connect to `127.0.0.1`
- Send request path as `GET http://request.example.org/test/ HTTP/1.1`
- Set `Host` header to `Host: host.example.org`

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET http://request.example.org/test/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: host.example.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.23.1
< Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 02:00:56 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 28
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
[host] = request.example.org
```

#### When only `Host` header exist ...

`$host` = `Host` header

```bash
curl http://127.0.0.1/test/ -v \
  -H "Host: host.example.org"
```

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: host.example.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.23.1
< Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 02:01:37 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 25
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
[host] = host.example.org
```

#### When none exist ...

`$host` = `server_name` (in Nginx config)

```bash
# HTTP 1.1 must have Host header, so use HTTP 1.0
curl http://127.0.0.1/test/ -v -H "Host:" -0
```

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /test/ HTTP/1.0
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.23.1
< Date: Fri, 21 Oct 2022 02:02:20 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 22
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
[host] = *.example.org
```

Ref: [ngx_http_core_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host), [Nginx `$host` validation](https://steelywing.github.io/note/Note/Nginx/host/#validation)

Comment: Excellent answer. The problem is, that "Host name from the request line" has the highest priority and will route the request to a `server` (vhost) even if the request has a bogus `Host` header and does not match `server_name`. This is an issue because applications behind nginx tend to use the passed on `Host` header. It's a pity that `server_name` does not check the `Host` header (if exists in the request) if there was a hostname  in "the request line" -- a rare and mostly malicious case.

Answer (score 0):

Both `$http_host` and `$host` are variables used in Nginx configuration files, but they have slight differences in their usage and behavior.

1. `$http_host`: This variable represents the value of the "Host" header in the HTTP request. It includes the port if specified by the client. For example, if the client sends a request to "example.com:8080", then `$http_host` will be set to "example.com:8080". This variable is useful when you need to capture the exact host value from the client request.
2. `$host`: This variable represents the name of the server requested by the client, without the port number. It only contains the hostname or IP address. For example, if the client sends a request to "example.com:8080", then `$host` will be set to "example.com". This variable is commonly used for server configuration, especially when defining server names or redirects.

To summarize, the main difference between `$http_host` and `$host` is that `$http_host` includes the port number specified by the client, while `$host` does not. In most cases, you would use `$host` when you need to capture the hostname for server-related configuration, and `$http_host` when you need to capture the complete "Host" header value with the port included.

Comment: is this chatgpt? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541