# nginx try_files with $host

Tags: web-services, nginx, fastcgi

In my configuration i use the host-name($host) as directory so i don't need to make a entry for each domain in the config (only for development purpose)

one issue is that try_files failed i tried different ways but all of them without success.

- try_files html\$host$uri =404;
- try_files $document_root\$host$uri =404;
- try_files $uri =404;
- try_files $document_root\$host$fastcgi_script_name =404;

  ```
  server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  default;

  charset UTF-8;

  #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

  # redirect server error pages to the static pages
  error_page  500 502 503 504  /error/50x.html;
  error_page  404 = /error/404.html;
  error_page  403 = /error/403.html;
  location ^~ /error/ {
      internal;
      root   html/default;
  }

  location / {
      root   html/$host;
      index  index.php index.html index.htm;
  }

  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
  location ~ \.php$ {
      #try_files html\$host$uri =404;
      #try_files $document_root\$host$uri =404;
      #try_files $uri =404;
      #try_files $document_root\$host$fastcgi_script_name =404;
      fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index  index.php;
      fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root\$host$fastcgi_script_name;
      include        fastcgi_params;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept it self is correct, but you are applying it in the wrong place, you should place this as a `root` for the server, not in the `try_files`

Also I believe you should use `$http_host` not `$host`, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414811/2149092) to know the difference

I don't know why your paths are not absolute, they should start with `/`

I'll add changes to your current posted config

```
server {
    #since you will match multiple domains I removed the server_name
    listen 80 default_server; 
    charset UTF-8; # don't really need this but it won't hurt.
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/$http_host; #assuming this path
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    # redirect server error pages to the static pages
    error_page  500 502 503 504  /error/50x.html;
    error_page  404 = /error/404.html;
    error_page  403 = /error/403.html;

    location ^~ /error/ {
        internal;
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/default;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
    # these are the minimal required parameters.
    include        fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

Comment: it was defined in the php block so that i can catch "No input file specified. " if a php file doesn't exist.

Comment: you should handle that in the `location /`, let me edit my answer