# nginx 301 drops port forwarded by vagrant

Tags: redirect, nginx, url-rewriting, vagrant

I have a vagrant vm running nginx on port 80.  My host machine forwards port 8080 to the vagrant vm's port 80.

I need to rewrite a url with a 301 redirect, which works, but the port I use to access nginx through the tunnel (8080) is dropped and the redirect fails.

```
http://server.com:8080/blog/two
```

*-becomes-*

```
http://server.com/blog.php?article=two
```

*- it should be -*

```
http://server.com:8080/blog.php?article=two
```

**example:**

```
rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ /blog.php?article=$1 last;
```

Thanks!

Comment: rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ http://$http_host/blog.php?article=$1 last;

[Whats the difference of host and http_host in nginx][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx

Comment: if you don't want the port `8080` then why is nginx listening to port `8080` and not `80`, or am i understanding it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Extract the original port number from the `Host` header field:

```
set $port '';

if ($http_host ~ :(\d+)$) {
    set $port :$1;
}

rewrite ^/blog/(.*)$ http://example.com$port/blog.php?article=$1;
```