# What's the difference of $http_host:$proxy_port and $host:$server_port in Nginx

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

The company that I work for, uses Nginx for Reverse Proxy and Load Balancer, so I just add an another block to nginx.conf file as shown below for the new service, when requesting Nginx server with `curl http://10.11.12.15:8080/api` Nginx returns 400 Bad Request, however after changing this configuration `proxy_set_header Host $http_host:$proxy_port;` to `proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;` solved Bad Request problem. But I don't get the point.

I have already read this answers [What's the difference of $host and $http_host in Nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx) and [Practical difference of $http_host and $host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971696/practical-difference-of-http-host-and-host).

But there isn't a clear answer for this situation. What is the difference between this headers ?

`proxy_set_header Host $http_host:$proxy_port;`

`proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;`

Used this block;

```
 upstream web-service {

    server 10.11.12.13:8080;
    server 10.11.12.14:8080 backup;
  }
  server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name myHost 10.11.12.15;
    location / {

      proxy_pass http://web-service;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host:$proxy_port;  # Throw HTTP 400 Bad Request
  #   proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;      # Working solution
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

`$http_host` already includes port when it's not default. Therefore it errors if you try to add a port again. `$host` doesn't include a port.