# Django-Ngix-Gunicorn returning wrong path for media files using Docker Compose

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, gunicorn

Im having trouble with a Django REST Framework App deployed in production mode using docker compose. The problem is when my endpoint returns the model with an ImageField it returns the wrong path, specifically missing the url port. Static files are working fine with the port included in the response url.

For example:

Current value: http://127.0.0.1/media/machines/034793bb-8516-45e3-a50a-4e00e7488617.png

Expected: http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/machines/034793bb-8516-45e3-a50a-4e00e7488617.png

**Settings.py**

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media') 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/app/static/'
```

** Docker file **

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["gunicorn", "-c", "config/gunicorn/conf.py", "--bind", ":8000", "--chdir", 
"app_api.wsgi:application"]
```

**Docker-compose**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  web-service:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "pip install -r requirements.txt && python manage.py makemigrations && python 
    manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && python manage.py runserver 
    0.0.0.0:8000"
    container_name: app_backend
    volumes:
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
      - .:/app
    depends_on: 
      - db
    restart: on-failure:2
  db:
    image: postgres
    container_name: app_postgres
    environment: 
      - POSTGRES_USER=bd_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=new_database
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes: 
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    restart: on-failure:2
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes: 
      - ./config/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - static:/app/static
      - media:/app/media
    depends_on: 
      - web-service
volumes:
  media:
  static:
  postgres: 
    driver: local
```

**Nginx config file**

```
upstream django_server {
    server web-service:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    location /static/ {
        alias /app/static/;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /app/media/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://django_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Fowarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

** Gunicorn config **

```
name = 'docker_django'
loglevel = 'info'
errorlog = '-'
accesslog = '-'
workers = 2
```

**Model**

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'machines', default='default.png')
    provider = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    data_source = models.ForeignKey(DataSource, related_name='data_source', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest option is to use `$http_host` in nginx instead of `$host` because `$host` does not contain port info. However `$http_host` may be empty from some clients.

```
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

[Differences described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414811/12520350)

As nginx knows nothing about `8000` port it is exposed on docker host there is no way for it to set it. One option is to take `Host` http header from request (which may not be present in request, probably in some rare cases).

Another option is to pass port nginx is exposed on as environmental variable into nginx container and use this variable in config appending to `$host` which for nginx can be done with `envsubst` run in custom entrypoint.

The reason it is working for static files - static files urls are included in templates (not api responses) with links relative to current web site root (whatever it is) and they do not need `build_absolute_uri()` to be run by django.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!