# Is there a way to get the baseuri of one of expose endpoints of nginx server with in lua?

Tags: nginx, lua, openresty

My nginx server have two endpoint. **/callback/model/** as one and second **/execute**
I want to get the complete uri of callback endpoint with in my execute.

```
eg: {http://ip:port}/callback/model/ or {domain}/callback/model/
```

Initially i tried constructing the uri as below

```
ngx.var.scheme .. "://" .. ngx.var.host ..":31003" .. "/callback/model/"
```

It works most the cases . But fails if I have domain or if port changes

Is there some way which nginx know the host its deployed and port details ?
My service is a dockerised nginx server.

Answer (score 1):

Nginx knows the IP address and port on which it get the request. You can try

```
ngx.var.scheme .. "://" .. ngx.var.server_addr .. ":" : ngx.var.server_port .. "/callback/model/"
```

although I don't know how would it work under dockerized environment.

Comment: Hi @Ivan Shatsky thanks for responding. Do you know whats the difference between $host and $server_addr ?

Comment: @Sarga `$server_addr` is an IP address on which nginx is bound, read about `$host` variable and its difference from `$http_host` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414810/whats-the-difference-of-host-and-http-host-in-nginx/15414811#15414811).

Comment: I am running a script that posts a request to my nginx on 127.0.0.1:8080/path the values i get in ngx.var.server_addr is not 127.0.0.1 . Is there a way to get the request ip address with in nginx in any of its vars?