# What should a proxy pass in the Host header?

Tags: nginx, proxy, http-headers, request-headers

Today I found out that `$host` and `$http_host` differ. At least `$host` doesn't contain the port number. Although there's [more to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414811/52499). My understanding is that people [usually do](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) `proxy_set_header Host $host`, which is... wrong? Is there some sort of general guideline?

Comment: Any reasoning behind downvoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`nginx-proxy`](https://hub.docker.com/r/jwilder/nginx-proxy) has [`proxy_set_header Host $http_host`](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/blob/0.8.0/nginx.tmpl#L128) in its config. Sounds like an authoritative source to me.