# Nginx Reverse Proxy to Allow CORS for Jasper Reports Server running on Tomcat Failing Preflight Request Access Control Check

Tags: angular, http, nginx, tomcat

I have an Angular Web Application and I need it to communicate with a Jasper Reports Server REST API running on Apache Tomcat. The problem I'm currently having is to enable CORS.

I have tried to enable CORS with the Tomcat Configuration but I have given up on that and am looking to create a reverse proxy using Nginx.

Tomcat is running on 192.168.21.18:8080 and I can access the Jasper Reports Sever on 192.168.21.18:8080/jasperserver/.
I am running the Angular Web Application using `ng serve` on my laptop.

I have tried creating the reverse proxy using the configuration below

```
server {
        listen 8081;

        server_name _;
        access_log      /var/log/nginx/tomcat-access.log;
        error_log       /var/log/nginx/tomcat-error.log;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

        
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {

                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

                return 204;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_redirect          off;
                rewrite                 /(.*) /$1  break;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080/;


        }

}
```

I am using the default Tomcat configuration and have only changed the configuration for the manager webapp.
I have disabled the RemoteAddrValve in `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml`

However, when I try to send a POST request to http://192.168.21.18:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions
I get this error.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.21.18/jasperserver/login.html' 
(redirected from 'http://192.168.21.18:8081/jasperserver/rest_v2/reportExecutions') 
from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't 
pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Comment: Can you add information on all the elements of your system of servers/proxies to your question? What is running on `localhost:4200` and `192.168.21.18:80`? The strange redirect from `http://192.168.21.18:8081/jasperserver` to `http://192.168.21.18/jasperserver` is due to your Tomcat's configuration: do you have a `RemoteIpValve`? Can you add its configuration?

Comment: I have added more information to the question based on your comment @PiotrP.Karwasz

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, you are getting redirected from `http://192.168.21.18:8081` to `http://192.168.21.18` (default port `80`).

While the exact logic behind URL generation depends on the code of JasperReports, servlet applications usually use the [`serverName`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getServerName--) and [`serverPort`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/servletrequest#getServerPort--) properties of the `ServletRequest` object to generate the authority part of the URL.

You need to configure NGINX to forward the `Host` header using:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

or

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:8081;
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15414810/11748454) for the difference between the two directives;

Alternatively, you can hardcode those values in Tomcat's `<Connector>` configuration (cf. [HTTP connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)):

```xml
<Connector ...
           proxyName="192.168.21.18"
           proxyPort="8081" />
```

**Remark**: Since you don't use the [`RemoteIpValve`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve), all those `X-Forwarded-*` headers you add to the request are never used by Tomcat.

Also, instead of using NGINX, you can configure a [`CorsFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter) in your `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml`, so that it applies to all applications.