# 400 Bad Request Error in an application using Django, Gunicorn, and Nginx

Tags: django, rest, nginx, gunicorn

I've been trying to troubleshoot my issue with no success for a while now, so I hope posting here helps. I am developing an application using Django REST Framework, Gunicorn, and Nginx. The idea is to have Gunicorn serve the Django applicaiton, and have Nginx be used as a reverse proxy that holds the SSL certs. I've referenced multiple guides on hosting applications using these three technologies, with little success.

I have my Django application connected to gunicorn using a sock file on port 80, and my Nginx server blocks listen for both port 80 and 433 (for SSL purposes). I have tried just about everything I can think of, and yet I am still getting a 400 - Bad Request error whenever I navigate to the domain that should serve the API. This is my Nginx sites-available file, with just a couple of names changed for security purposes:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.querymarketplace.net;
    return 301 http://querymarketplaceapi.net$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name querymarketplaceapi.net 157.245.10.103;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/jbisc/qm_marketplace/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/jbisc/qm_marketplace.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl; # Optional: Add IPv6 support
    server_name querymarketplaceapi.net;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/querymarketplaceapi.net/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/querymarketplaceapi.net/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /static/ {
        root /home/jbisc/qm_marketplace/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/jbisc/qm_marketplace.sock;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }
}
```

I have tested gunicorn and my Django application, and can confirm that the issue must lie with Nginx.

Comment: Did you add your hostnames to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` in the sttings?

Comment: Yes. I added both the custom domain, and the server IP for the VM that is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` instead of `proxy_set_header Host $host;`. (even it shouldn't make a difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414811/4151233)

Furthermore, add `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;` and add

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO", "https")
```

to your settings.py file. Read more about `SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER` in the  [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#secure-proxy-ssl-header).

`X-Forwarded-Host` should not be needed when `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` is used. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts).

A typical set of headers for a Django project with nginx could look like this:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```